# Delphi: Changing focus after deleting a node from a virtual string tree

Tags: delphi, focus, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have a component of type `TVirtualStringTree` (let us call it `VST`). It has nodes in the form of a list, i.e. all the nodes are at the same level. I want to change a focus after deleting a node (with the `DeleteNode` method) and I used `OnFreeNode` event:

```
procedure TMyForm.VSTFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  NewFocus: PVirtualNode;
begin
  NewFocus := VST.GetNext(Node);
  if not Assigned(newFocus) then
    NewFocus := VST.GetPrevious(Node);
  if Assigned(NewFocus) then
  begin
    VST.FocusedNode := NewFocus;
    VST.Selected[NewFocus] := True
  end;
end;
```

I want also the change to cause some reactions, e.g. set the `Enabled` property of a button:

```
procedure TMyForm.VSTFocusChanged(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex);
begin
  btn1.Enabled := Assigned(Node);
end;
```

But there are some problems with the solution. For example, when I close the form with the Cancel button (the form is open with `ShowModal` method), the nodes are freed, `VSTFocusChanged` is triggered, and the later throws an exception because of nil button. Of course, I could check if the button is assigned, but is there more elegant solution of changing the focus after deleting a node without this undesirable effect (and without other undesirable effects)?

Answer (score 5):

### Is there a built-in way to always have a node selected?

Yes, there is. Remove your code from those events and include the **toAlwaysSelectNode** option to the tree view **TreeOptions.SelectionOptions** option set (e.g. enable it in the IDE). The comment by this option says:

> If this flag is set to true, the tree view tries to always have a node
>   selected.

That includes node deletion as well.

---

### How to safely update foreign control's enabled state from VT event?

The problem you were facing is that you were focusing node manually from the **OnFreeNode** event which in turn triggered **OnFocusChanged** event. And since nodes are freed also when the control is destroyed and that button was destroyed before, you were trying to access a destroyed control. To avoid this in the future you can use [**RTL actions**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/RTL_Actions) because there's a lot of events which VT fires even when it has **csDestroying** state signalled (including event like **OnStructureChange**) and actions are one safe workaround.

Something like this should work safely (I'm not a fan of action **OnUpdate** event):

```
procedure TMyForm.VSTStructureChange(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Reason: TChangeReason);
begin
  { ActionDeleteNode is assigned to the button's Action property; SelectedCount
    is a bit paranoic here because if you use the toAlwaysSelectNode option, at
    least one node should be always selected, so RootNodeCount > 0 could do the
    same here }
  ActionDeleteNode.Enabled := Sender.SelectedCount > 0;
end;
```

Without RTL actions you can safely update that button state e.g. right after you perform an action, for example after you delete node:

```
VST.DeleteNode(VST.FocusedNode);
ButtonDeleteNode.Enabled := VST.SelectedCount > 0;
```

But with that you can get out of sync and write more code. Hence using RTL actions is what would I prefer.

Comment: `if Assigned(ButtonDeleteNode) then...` - who/what guarantees that the `ButtonDeleteNode` is set to `nil` when it is destroyed? It's another thing OP should take care of.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't thinking about it. I just took that from the question in a hope that VCL destroys the control and unassign its reference. But haven't found a note in the help about it. Will remove that..

Comment: Again, `ButtonDeleteNode` might be already freed at the `OnStructureChange`. so this is why I'm against using this event for updating "actions". You will need to use some flag so you can bail this event.

Comment: And I'm against clumsy `OnUpdate` action event. It is safe to update action (but not safe to access "foreign" control) from there.